# Unexpected error when running batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to batch process several files with a very simple batch file, however, every time that I run the .bat I get `\MODIS\MOSIAC\2000\*mos.hdf was unexpected at this time`

I have tried various fixes for quoting issues but nothing seems to work.

The full code is as follows

`FOR %i IN (E:\MODIS\MOSIAC\2000mos\*mos.hdf) DO resample -p (E:\MODIS\MODISRepro\OntarioReproject2000.prm) -i %i -o %i.tif`

What could be a possible fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

Within a batch file you need to double-up the `%` signs on `%x` variables:

```
FOR %%i IN (E:\MODIS\MOSIAC\2000mos\*mos.hdf) DO resample -p (E:\MODIS\MODISRepro\OntarioReproject2000.prm) -i %%i -o %%i.tif
```